# Is it permissible to work in a NGO that has a microfinance program, which is also one of it's source of fund?

Tags: riba

Praise to Almighty Allah.

After more than 1.5 years of being unemployed, I finally got an offer from an International NGO (BRAC,www.brac.net) to work as an IT advisor in their Health, Nutrition and Population Program (HNPP). BRAC has several program, HNPP, Education, poverty alleviation, social development, and **Microfinance** (this one is RIBA). It gets funds from various donor agency, social enterprises funded by BRAC and **earning from Microfinance**. They also have an investment in retail bank (own 44% of BRAC bank) . My job doesn't involve working with microfinance program and exclusive to HNPP only.

I know that working in Bank is not permissible, not even as janitor.

My question is should I accept this job offer from this organization which has a microfinance program?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you suggesting that working in a bank is not permissible? I find that baffling. Generally one has to take into account its lending and borrowing policies and so long as these are not predatory and are sharia compliant and so socially responsible and which will depend upon the country in question as well as how much exposure they have to international markets, it's not haram per se - which is what your question is making out.

Comment: I am considering the Bank that involves RIBA as non permissible.